# How to enable the abilities wheel for Might, Finesse and Sorcery abilities?

Tags: ps4, kingdoms-of-amalur-re-reckoning

I'm playing Kingdoms of Amalur: Re-reckoning on the PS4. While I've leveled up and selected some of the special abilities, e.g. Might: Quake, Finesse: Shadow Flare, Sorcery: Storm Bolt, I've been unable to actually use them.  When I enter combat, the ability wheel appears in the lower right corner of the screen, but I don't know how to engage any of the buttons. For example, Quake is the circle button, yet when I press it the action performed is the dodge. I found a reddit thread that says to press R1 first, but that also performs the default action of crouching for stealth.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

It is L2+R2.

I reached Mel Senshir and battled the Balor, during which I went into Reckoning mode with the L2+R2 combo, and I must have done it twice by accident because suddenly the Abilities wheel became enabled.

This is at level 28, I can't believe I've played this far into the game without realizing how to do this.